# UIViewController in NSObject not presenting when calling presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i'm new with iPhone developpement and i try to lunch a UIviewController when the user pressed a button witch will allow the user too send an email.

So my AppControler is a NSObject witch contains a UIWindow and a UIViewController* myViewController

When i detect the click on the button i create this:

```
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker =
 [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainWindow"
 bundle:nil];

  picker.mailComposeDelegate = myViewController;
```

... set the mail

and then when i try to present the view controller with this

```
 [myViewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

 [picker release];
```

Nothing append..

i know it's simple but i cant figured it out what is wrong.

thanks

Comment: OK, i'm going to ask the stupid, obvious questions, but are you absolutely sure that your IB outlets are valid, and that myViewController actually points at the view controller? A breakpoint on [myViewController presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES] should point you in the right direction...

Comment: humm, i'm not familiar with the IB oulets.. i dont know what you're talking about, i didnt see any IBOulets in my code sorry

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

[**self** presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

As @dannywartnaby mentioned unless myViewController points to the current view controller (self) it won't work.

Comment: the view controller is not self because self is a NSOjects so i can't do a presentModalViewController on self

how can i check if myViewController points on the good controller?